# How to get the TextBox value in controller action in ASP.NET Core MVC application without using jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am a newbie in ASP.NET Core MVC. Trying to make a simple update page where the model (coming from another data service) is bound with a table. On each row there is a update button. There are some fields which are mapped to the text box and are editable.

I want to get the editable values in text box within the controller without using jQuery or AJAX. I am sure there must be a way in plain ASP.NET Core capabilities.

**Model:**

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<AspNetCoreMVC.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
}

<table class="table" style="width:fit-content">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Location)
            </th>
            <th>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Location)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Update","UpdateAction","Home",new { updatedLocation = item.Location })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using AspNetCoreMVC.Models;

namespace AspNetCoreMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>();
            employees.Add(new Employee { Name="Abcd", Location="abcdLocation1"});
            employees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Efgh", Location = "EfghLocation2" });
            return View(employees);
        }

        public IActionResult UpdateAction(string updatedLocation)
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>();
            employees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Abcd", Location = "abcdLocation1" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Efgh", Location = "EfghLocation2" });
            return View("Index", employees);
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I only get the same value as bound by the cell template textbox.

How can I make sure the changed text in the textbox location is received in the controller please?

Comment: Use a `<form>` and submit that form to the server.  Currently you just have a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this worked when I used the `@Html.EditorFor()` helper instead of the `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helper, with setting the `name` attribute.

Therefore, try the following:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateAction", "Home"))
        {                
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>     
                    @* Setting the `name` attribute explicitly *@               
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => item.Location, "name", "updatedLocation")
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div><input type="submit" value="Update" /></div>                  
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Because of the binding context will already have the `updatedLocation` name, you don't need to define it in the `Html.BeginForm()`.

And the `[HttpPost]` attribute should be added to the`UpdateAction()` action method declaration:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateAction(string updatedLocation)
{
    ...
}
```

---

*NOTE: An additional option is using the `<input>` tag instead of `@Html.EditorFor()` helper:*

```
<input id="updatedLocation" name="updatedLocation" type="text" value="@item.Location" />
```

Comment: I tried this but what do I set for the link "Update" so that I get the updated text box value from the web page ?

@Html.ActionLink("Update","UpdateAction","Home",new { updatedLocation = item.Location })

Comment: @hi_shobhit76: To make what you want (without JQuery) you MUST to use POST, but the  `@Html.ActionLink` performs GET verb. Therefore, I replaced  the `@Html.ActionLink` by `<div><input type="submit" value="Update" /></div>`. Did you try replace `<tbody>` block in your code by code fragment in the answer above?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt notice the other change. It works great now !

Comment: how do we capture the whole model for that row with the changes I do in the text box. It is something like two way binding how we do in WPF, that if we change the property or control value change is reflected during execution. Is there a concept of two way binding with the html controls in MVC ?

Comment: @hi_shobhit76: _**Q)** how do we capture the whole model for that row with the changes ...?_ **A)** WPF and MVC are using totally different approach for data binding. If in WPF we have _live connection_ between source and target (by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) in the MVC we don't have it. Connection between server and client in the MVC is based on the HTTP protocol that is stateless. This means that every request is processing independently. See [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: @hi_shobhit76: _**continued)**_ If the view model is single object you do nothing. The binding context already will contain all information required for data binding. But when we have a collection of objects it is necessary to write some additional code. You can look at this post: [Return ViewData from view to controller razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70380959/6630084) or if it not much helpful put a new question with details on SO and we will try to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will definitely look at this and try to make it more business logic friendly. Thats the whole idea behind the extended question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a form outside `<tr>`:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
        <form asp-action="UpdateAction" asp-controller="Home" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Location)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        }
    </tbody>
```

And because name attribute bind with the property name in action,try to change your action like this:

```
public IActionResult UpdateAction(string Location)
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>();
            employees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Abcd", Location = "abcdLocation1" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Efgh", Location = "EfghLocation2" });
            return View("Index", employees);
        }
```